# Windows 8.1 doesn't save some settings (default app, folder and icon size, etc..)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, windows-registry

this start happening 3 days ago, every time i try to open a file that is not "recognized by windows by default", for example, a torrent file, a .java script, an iso image, etc...
Every time i do that the "search for application to open this file in Windows store" message popup, even if i right click on the file -> property -> change the default application-> apply-> ok.

first of all the file icon doesn't change, which is strange, but also, when i double click on it again, it still give me the same message saying that there is no default app to open this file.

Also normally when i change the icon size or the view mode inside some folder, usually when i open that folder again, it had to use the last settings but it doesn't, it get beck to "default" or something.

I also installed cCleaner and fixed all registry issues and restated the computer, still no help.

Any help please ?

**UPDATE:**

i just went to control panel -> default program, and was really surprised by the list there, it doesn't even have 1/4 of the installed programs i have in my computer, what's wrong ? :
[image]

Also this is what happens when i change the default app from the file property :
[image]

My Specs :

> Os : Windows 8.1
>
> Cpu : intel i7-4770 3.40Ghz
>
> Gpu : nVidia GTX-750
>
> Ram : 8Gb
>
> HDD : 2tb

Comment: I wouldn't recommend randomly using CCleaner...but since you already did, whatever. Have you run a virus scan? I would recommend [MSE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download) and [MBAM](https://www.malwarebytes.org/). Before you scan though, try running a command prompt and enter `sfc/ scannow`. See if that finds any problems or fixes it for you.

Comment: sfc/scannow said (original was in French so..) : "Scan was successfully completed and found corrupted files, however, it couldn't fix them all, for more details see log file CBS.log" [here is a link](https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/CBS.log?_subject_uid=88553415&w=AAAdZpRjo_GWKLuqmbc6HqZeFMX9Pzdgd_kEhkfPDarB8w) to that file (it's 8mb with more than 45k lines....)

Comment: Can't view it, must be private or something. Try posting it on one of those Windows specific forums, they are usually helpful with those.

Comment: sorry here is [another link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/itu7b40nnu05pb6/CBS.log?dl=0)

Comment: Is anything better now if you restart the computer? And did you ever scan for malware? I'm not familiar with CBS logs but it seems like just a few files related to drivers that could not be repaired.

Comment: yeah still had the same problem, i think am gonna let windows install the updates and see what happens (i've been avoiding updates for few months now because of it broke my VmWare OsX virtual machine)

Comment: i just updated the post, maybe you have an idea about what's happening now, thanks